# Python script creating unexpected blank rows in csv (using bottle, csv, os)

Tags: python, csv, cookies, bottle

Initial users.csv file- columns are respectively username,real name,password.

```
  fraud,mike ross,iloveharveynew
  abc,ab isss c,coolgal
  xyz,name last,rockpassnew
```

Algorithm- 
 1. Input username (from a cookie) & new-password from a html form.
 2. Iterate over the csv file to print all the rows that do not contain 'username' to a new file final.csv 
 3. Remove users.csv file. 
 4. Append username,real name,new password to final.csv file. 
 5. Rename final.csv to users.csv

For instance, let's say user xyz was logged in and username=xyz was retrieved from cookie. The user changed the password to rockpassnewnew.

Output users.csv file-

```
  fraud,mike ross,iloveharveynew

  abc,ab isss c,coolgal



  xyz,name last,rockpassnewnew
```

Here is the functioned defined that does this which is called from a controller-

```
def change(self, new_password):
        errors = []

        if len(new_password) < 3: errors.append('new password too short')

        if errors:
            return errors

        else:
            with open('users.csv','r') as u:

                users = csv.reader(u)
                with open('final.csv', 'a') as f:
                    final=csv.writer(f)
                    for line in users:
                        variableforchecking1 = bottle.request.get_cookie('username')
                        if variableforchecking1 not in line:
                            final.writerow(line)
            os.remove('users.csv')
            variableforchecking1 = bottle.request.get_cookie('username')
            variableforchecking2 = bottle.request.get_cookie('real_name')

            with open('final.csv', 'a') as f:
                final=csv.writer(f)
                final.writerow([variableforchecking1, variableforchecking2, new_password])
            os.rename ('final.csv','users.csv')
            return []
```

The controller code which calls this function is-

```
@bottle.get('/change')
def change():

    return bottle.template('change')


@bottle.post('/change')
def changePost():
    new_password = bottle.request.forms.get('new-password')
    username = me.username()

    errors = me.change(new_password)
    if errors:
        return bottle.template('change', errors=errors)

    me.login(username, new_password)
    return bottle.redirect('/home')
```

**How to prevent these blank rows from being created because every time a password is changed, the number of blank rows increase considerably?**

Comment: One thing: have you checked the value of your cookies for newlines?

Comment: Also, your algo as is will inadvertently delete users whose password or real name happen to equal the username of the user changing their password.  I'd suggest `if variableforchecking1 == line[0]` instead of `if variableforchecking1 not in line`

Comment: How do I do that (check value of cookie for newlines) and as for the algo deleting other users, nice observation, thanks. Will correct that.

Comment: typo before: `if variableforchecking1 != line[0]`

Comment: well, for instance just print out the value after using `get_cookie()` and see if there is an extra newline.  Also, same for `new_password`

Comment: There isn't, I just checked.

Answer (score 0):

When opening a CSV file to be written to using a `csv.writer`, take care how you open the file.

The problem is that `csv.writer` does its own handling of line-endings.  If a file opened with `open` is not opened carefully, the file object will also replace LF line-endings with CR+LF when writing data.  So when both are making these changes, the line endings in the output file can become CR+CR+LF.  Text editors will often interpret this as two line endings.

The fix is to open the file in binary mode in Python 2, or with `newline=''` in Python 3 [as recommended by the documentation for the `csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer).  To do this, replace both occurrences of

```
            with open('final.csv', 'a') as f:
```

with

```
            with open('final.csv', 'ab') as f:
```

if you are using Python 2, or

```
            with open('final.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
```

if you are using Python 3.

Comment: When I do that, I get the following error:


  File "C:\Users\Utkarsh\Documents\mvc-for-begginers-changepass - experiment\user.py", line 81, in change
    final.writerow(line)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Comment: @UtkarshMittal: sorry, I wasn't aware you were using Python 3.  I've modified my answer to cater for Python 3.

Comment: I don't know what hapenned, but this further messed up the output csv, now iit not only has empty rows but repeated rows too.